# Rails suddenly needs an template.. when its there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've been setting up views acquiesced with AJAX all afternoon, and suddenly one of them snags and gives me this error :

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template tabs/tabs_result.erb in view path app/views:vendor/plugins/rails-ckeditor/app/views):
```

Strange..

**my routes**

```
organization.resources :tabs, :collection => {:tabs_result => :get}
```

**produces this route:**

```
 tabs_result_organization_tabs GET    /organizations/:organization_id/tabs/tabs_result(.:format)
```

I've never needed an action in the controller so I just skip that.

I have a file here `/tabs/tabs_result.js.haml`

**And I call it with this line :**

```
= link_to tab.title, tabs_result_organization_tabs_path(organization, tab), :class => 'show-result'
```

Anyone know why that error is popping up ?

I thought I would also point out that if I renamed the file it `tabs_result.js.erb` even though its not, and I don't want it to be, it gives me this error :

```
ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to tabs_result. Actions: create, destroy, edit, edit_order, new, show, update, and update_order):
```

Comment: Check and see if your controller is formatted to return format.js for that action.

Comment: That's what I thought but none of my other identical Ajax calls have a corresponding action in the controller.

Comment: Are any of your other Ajax calls to custom methods though? If you don't have an action in your controller for tabs_result, your app can't respond to it. It can be super simple (i.e. no real code) but routes need actions.

Comment: What type of action (get/put etc.) is the log showing as being received when the link is clicked?

Comment: @Zabba, Processing TabsController#tabs_result to #<tab:0x104777040> (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-02-10 15:47:58) [GET] But so is my other ajax call Processing `ReviewsController#reviews_result` even though there is no action in the controller called reviews_result

Comment: Don't you need to add `:remote => true` in `link_to` when wanting to use AJAx?

Comment: @Zabba, this is a Rails 2 project. I *think* that's Rails 3 though I could be amiss on this one.

Comment: Yes, thats in Rails 3. Just to be sure, you are making a plugin called `rails-ckeditor` ? Making sure that Rails isn't looking into the wrong folder for some reason, cos the view is being called from the `vendor` folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the rails that you're requesting an Ajax response.

I'm assuming you're trying to render the response after a "click" event.

So to all your links you could add a class called "ajaxLink" and add the following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.ajaxLink").live("click", function(){
    $.getScript($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
  });
}
```